# how to declare and define global variables in order to access them from all headers/source files properly

Tags: c++, c, global-variables

Well, I'm *learning* C++ and never really learned how to do stuff that is not OO.
I'm trying to get a bit more experience coding in C style.

### GobalInformation.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef GLOBALINFORMATION_H
#define GLOBALINFORMATION_H

#include "MapInformation.h"

namespace gi {
    MapInformation mapInf;
};

#endif
```

I would like to be able to access gi::mapInf from every header and cpp in my project. Right now I'm including globalinformation.h in every header, so I'm getting linker errors with multiple definitions.

How can I work around the problem?

Comment: You may think now that you want this global variable, but  I assure you will regret it.

Comment: @BjörnPollex elaborate please

Comment: OT: Why do you use `#pragma once` **and** header guards (BTW, without unique identifiers => dangerous)?

Comment: @Andre Hmm, I read it at wikipedia once it might be good to do it : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm learning C++, better? :) I know about templates though!

Comment: @xcrypt - Listen to Björn! :-) Once you have actually accessed this variable from every header and cpp in your project, you will come back here and ask why its value changed unexpectedly. C++ added `private` class members for a reason!

Comment: @BoPersson The question is why would/could that happen?

Comment: @xcrypt: When using header guards you should append a unique part to avoid name clashes. You could add a GUID like so: `#ifndef GLOBALINFORMATION_H_8FF7B23E1B4D11E18852C5D64824019B`, `#define GLOBALINFORMATION_H_8FF7B23E1B4D11E18852C5D64824019B`. If you don't need portability I would recommend to only use `#pragma once` if your compiler supports it.

Comment: @Andre I see your point, but I haven't been taught it like that. Seems a bit inconvenient though... I'll keep it in mind when doing more serious projects. Thanks :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In header file only do

```
namespace gi {
    extern MapInformation mapInf;
};
```

In CPP file provide the actual definition.

```
namespace gi {
    MapInformation mapInf;
};
```

It will work as you intend.

If you are using the **MapInformation** across dynamic link library boundaries you might have to link against the library that includes the definition cpp file. Also on Window you might have to use **[dllimport/dllexport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx)**

Comment: Note that the definition must be in *exactly one* translation-unit.

Comment: in globalinformation.cpp I should do "MapInformation mapInf;"?

Comment: @xcrypt .. I have updated my answer to reflect what to do in CPP file

Comment: what does that mean: "f you are using the MapInformation across dynamic link library boundaries you might have to link against the library that includes the definition cpp file." can you explain more?

Answer (score 17):

Be aware that having globals in multiple compilation units can easily lead to order-of-initialization problems.  You may wish to consider replacing each global with a function that returns a reference.  In your case, put this in one cpp file and declare it in the header:

```
namespace gi {
    MapInformation& getMapInf()
    {
        static MapInformation result;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps explain what is the cause of this order-of-intialization problem in your answer?

Comment: @xcrypt: The order in which global objects are initialized is unspecified (across TUs), so if you have one global object that requires another one, you can't be certain that they'll be initialized in the correct order. Having a local static object (which is essentially also global, just with restricted visibility) avoids this because you are guaranteed that the object will have been constructed by the time `getMapInf()` returns.

Comment: I suppose this function should be inlined or declared extern? Well, I had to, anyway

Comment: Good suggestion, but I have another question: How can I set the "global" variable in your case? How can I write a set-Method?

Comment: @xMutzelx, You can set or get the value of the global by using the reference returned by getMapInf(). E.g. gi::MapInformation otherMapInf(); getMapInf() = otherMapInf();

Comment: Thank you, that helped me alot!

Answer (score 3):

Global variables are C, but namespaces are C++. There is a good discussion on using global variables and how they can be replaced by Singleton pattern: [Globals and Singletons](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/339420)

And here is a simple sample: [CPP/Classes/Singleton](http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/CPP/Classes/Singleton)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a better solution is to create a global object that contains all your global data. Then pass a smart pointer to the classes that actually need to access this shared global data. 
Example:

```
class GlobalData
{
public:
    int ticks_;
};   


//Other file
class ThatNeedsGlobalData
{
public:
ThatNeedsGlobalData(std::shared_ptr<GlobalData> globalData);
};
```

This will save you some trouble.

Good luck!

Comment: That would also be a possible solution, so I will vote up. But one of the reason I want it as global is to prevent each class from having a reference to the information  (saving memory). It might not matter much in the end, but hey, I think it's cool :p

Comment: So you want to save the size of a pointer/smart pointer in each class that needs access to the global data? Ok. Just try it and see if you think it is worth it. You can always try other solutions later.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things that you need to take care of while trying to use global variables the way you have used.

1. Ensure that all the header files that the header files that GobalInformation.h includes are also enclosed insides #ifndefs. (I could not see mapinformation.h so I assume you have done it)
2. Just like CPP, C compiler also does not ensure order of the initialization of variables in different translation units(different C/CPP files). 
   Hence declare the header file as

   ```
   //GlobalInformation.h

   namespace gi {
       extern MapInformation mapInf;
   };
   ```
3. In a function that you know would be called first initialize the variable. This way lazy-initialization can also be acheived in C.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with [2], please elaborate? Seems important