# Linking error using CMake to create a shared library in C++ because multiple definition of symbol

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, linker-errors, multiple-definition-error

I'm having problems to compile my code, that links with POCO C++ libraries, to create a shared library for Linux (Mint 13, just in case). This is my reduced environment.

I have these 3 files:

**IL_Notify.h**

```
#ifndef __IL_NOTIFY_H__
#define __IL_NOTIFY_H__

#include <string>
#include "Poco/Logger.h"
#include "Poco/LogStream.h"

using Poco::Logger;
using Poco::LogStream;

namespace mynamespace
{
    // Get logger. Inherits root channel
    LogStream lstr(Logger::get("MyLogger"));

    // From any other class, call logger this way:
    //lstr << "This is a test" << std::endl;
}

#endif
```

**IL_Class1.cpp**

```
#include "IL_Class1.h"
#include "IL_Notify.h"

namespace mynamespace {

    void IL_Class1::foo()
    {
        // Stuff...

        lstr << "This is a test msg from IL_Class1::foo" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**IL_Class2.cpp**

```
#include "IL_Class2.h"
#include "IL_Notify.h"

namespace mynamespace {

    void IL_Class2::bar()
    {
        // Stuff...

        lstr << "This is a test msg from IL_Class2::bar" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

`IL_Class1` and `IL_Class2` are declared at `IL_Class1.h` and `IL_Class2.h`. No inclussion of `IL_Notify.h` inside those headers.

And this is my **CMakeLists.txt** file

```
# Set search path to find PocoConfig.cmake
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/)


# Look for needed packages
find_package(Poco REQUIRED)

# Now, we can use poco
include_directories(
    ${Poco_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)

# Libraries which we are linking against
link_directories(
    ${Poco_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)

# Get all the cpp files to build my library
file(GLOB_RECURSE all_sources
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/IL_Class1.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/IL_Class2.cpp
)

# Library creation
add_library(mylib SHARED ${all_sources})
```

I can execute `cmake` successfully, to create the `Makefile`. But when I run `make`, **I get this error**

```
CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/src/IL_Class2.cpp.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `mynamespace::lstr'
CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/src/IL_Class1.cpp.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libmylib.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So, even when I'm preventing headers to be included twice, via `#ifndef`, `make` can't compile my code because a symbol declared in that header is detected twice. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to declare and define global variables in order to access them from all headers/source files properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317010/how-to-declare-and-define-global-variables-in-order-to-access-them-from-all-head)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing my question is duplicated, I got the right solution.

My `IL_Notify.h`

```
#ifndef __IL_NOTIFY_H__
#define __IL_NOTIFY_H__

#include <string>
#include "Poco/Logger.h"
#include "Poco/LogStream.h"

using Poco::Logger;
using Poco::LogStream;

namespace openil
{
    // Get logger. Inherits root channel
    extern LogStream lstr;
}

#endif
```

My **new** `IL_Notify.cpp`

```
#include "IL_Notify.h"

namespace openil
{
    // TODO: More flexibility here: more channels, different formatting...
    // Maybe a IL_Utils function should do that

    // Get logger. Inherits root channel
    LogStream lstr(Logger::get("OpenILLogger"));

    // From any other class, call logger this way:
    //lstr << "This is a test" << std::endl;
}
```