# Read variable from C++ header in Objective-c

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I am trying access a variable defined in a C++ header file in Objective-C.Its always returning 0. I do not have any ways to alter the CPP header since its a third party library.

I would like to know how I can access the methods and variables in the header file.

Any sample or reference will be helpful.

Comment: Any code would be helpful too

Comment: Please show a relevant portion of the header file, the part where you include the header in the `.mm`-file, and the code that accesses the variable.

Comment: Make sure your file is `.mm` not `.m`.

Comment: I have renamed my .m to .mm and here is a sample code.

 CPPEng *a = NULL;
 CPPRes result = CPPEng_GetInstance(&a);

This result must have the values but now its showing as 0

Comment: @StephanLechner Here is the code  
I have renamed my .m to .mm and here is a sample code. CPPEng *a = NULL; CPPRes result = CPPEng_GetInstance(&a); This result must have the values but now its showing as 0

Comment: edit you question paste contents of your header file and relevant parts of you `*.mm`/`*.m`/`*.cpp` code. Do not paste code in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have problems with multiple definitions when defining a variable in a header file ([how to declare and define global variables in order to access them from all headers/source files properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317010/how-to-declare-and-define-global-variables-in-order-to-access-them-from-all-head)).

Can you stop including the header file and instead add a line such as:

```
extern CPPEng *a;
```